Getting Error "(1): The requested resource does not exist" while creating sandbox through Salesforce CLI
Getting Error "(1): The requested resource does not exist" while creating sandbox through Salesforce CLI

sfdx org create sandbox -f config/dev-sandbox-def.json --target-org DevHubOr --wait 30
=== Config Sandbox Request
Field        Value  ────────────
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
SandboxName  devopstest  Type         Developer  AutoActivate true
LicenseType  Developer  Company      Acme  Country      US  FirstName
TestUser  LastName     Lastname  Email        myemail@domain.com
Edition      Developer  Features
MultiCurrency;API;AuthorApex;CustomTabs;CustomApps;ForceComPlatform ?
Is the configuration correct? yes Sandbox Create... done Error (1):
The requested resource does not exist

dev-sandbox-def.json
{
  "SandboxName": "devopstest",
  "Type": "Developer",
  "AutoActivate": true,
  "LicenseType": "Developer",
  "Company": "Acme",
  "Country": "US",
  "FirstName":"TestUser ",
  "LastName": "Lastname",
  "Email": "myemail@domain.com",
  "Edition": "Developer",
  "Features": "MultiCurrency;API;AuthorApex;CustomTabs;CustomApps;ForceComPlatform"
}

Dev Hub is set to default

